# MAC Printing - Pausing

Tags: mac, printing, network-printer, cups

I have a script that maps our printers, it uses PPD files.
When I map the printers using the script it will pause in the middle of the printing process, like it will say printing then PAUSE this is happening everytime. But when I add the printer manually, like going through the UI to add printers it will print without issues. Any ideas why this is happening?

Below is how I set the printers to be mapped:

do shell script "lpadmin -p (printername) -v (Printer address) -P (PPD File Location) -o printer-is-shared=false -E"

I also reset printer settings, but this is only happening when mapping via the script.

Thank you all for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption clause is causing the issue. Once I added encryption=no to the printer address it works.